# Why does std::not1() take parameter by const reference instead of by value?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std

`std::not1()` is prototyped as follows:

```
template< class Predicate >
std::unary_negate<Predicate> not1(const Predicate& pred);
```

This effectively prohibits move semantics. Why isn't it prototyped as:

```
template< class Predicate >
std::unary_negate<Predicate> not1(Predicate pred);
```

This way, copy or move depends on how `pred` is constructed. The function then just moves `pred` to the constructed `std::unary_negate` object.

Comment: They could add additional overload for rvalues, but nobody actually cared about those nongeneric helpers when you have lambdas. And soon they would superseded with universal reference accepting `not_fn` anyway.

Comment: @hvd Just removed `constexpr` and fallback to C++03.

Comment: @Lingxi That seems perfectly reasonable to me, thanks.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot As to now, the syntax is simpler using `std::not1()` than using a lambda.

Comment: @Lingxi Not really; you need to get all the `result_type`/`argument_type` boilerplate typedefs into the type, plus make extra wrapping calls for function/member pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be completely useless to make that change by itself. What `not1` does is construct a `std::unary_negate<Predicate>` using `pred` as an argument to the constructor. But the only relevant constructor of `std::unary_negate<Predicate>` takes `const Predicate &`, *not* `Predicate &&`.

The logical follow-up question would be, why doesn't `std::unary_negate<Predicate>` have a constructor taking `Predicate &&`? It clearly couldn't have taken such an argument when it was designed, because rvalue references didn't exist yet. As for later, that's a bit of a guess, but I'd say lambdas already fill the need quite well, so there's not much point in `unary_negate` any longer other than backwards compatibility.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Still, I would prefer `std::not1()` to a lambda, cause it's simpler in syntax and much more intuitive and readable.

Comment: @Lingxi If the standard library were designed from scratch, I suppose `std::not1` might be defined as returning an unspecified return type, so that it could be implemented by returning a lambda. :) Unfortunately, making that change now would break backwards compatibility too.